# Snapshot return array

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I've created a web socket server with Node.js to connect two Flutter apps. I can post a message to server but when I listen to it on WebApp i receive an array [79,101] instead message (Oi). How can I solve it?

Sink Message

```
 void _sendMessage(data) {
    widget.channel.sink.add('Oi');
  }
```

Cliente Stream Builder

```
 StreamBuilder(
              stream: channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) { 
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : 'Null');
              },
            )
```

Node.js Server

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
// start the server and specify the port number
const port = 8080;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: port }); 
console.log(`[WebSocket] Starting WebSocket server on localhost:${port}`);
wss.on('connection', (ws, request) => { 
  const clientIp = request.sock.remoteAddress;
console.log(`[WebSocket] Client with IP ${clientIp} has connected`); 
ws.send('Connected!');
// Broadcast aka send messages to all connected clients
 ws.on('message', (message) => {
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => { 
      if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) { 
        client.send(message); } })
console.log(`[WebSocket] Message ${message} was received`); });
});
```

Comment: what's stored in the array of "snapshot.data"?

Comment: when i print data returns [79, 105]

Comment: its translate to Oi (utf8) but I just cannot convert AsyncSnapshot<Object?> snapshot to String :-(

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution you are looking for but I would try and convert the response via `String.fromCharCode`since the response might be ASCII characters to begin my way of debugging.